# Lightning checkbox checked when page loads

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputcheckboxes

Why this event not firing? and I have clear the cache and tried every possible thing.
So I'm trying to see if the `checked` is `true/false` which the value coming from database.

HTML:

```
<lightning-input data-id="toggle1" type="toggle"
                checked={isChecked}
                onchange={changeToggle}></lightning-input>
....
....
<lightning-input data-id="toggle10" type="toggle"
                checked={isChecked}
                onchange={changeToggle}></lightning-input>
```

JS:

```
isChecked(event) {
    const checkboxList = this.data;
    for (const c of checkboxList) {
        debugger;
    }
}
```

is there any reason for not calling this function `isChecked` when the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`checked` is a Boolean attribute, not an event handler. All event handlers start with `on`.  You use `checked` to set the component's state. The checkbox would be checked because you're passing in a function object, which is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Comment: I realized later thanks for reminding.

Comment: @NickKahn If I had a dime for every single silly mistake I've made, I'd likely have taken a vacation by now, lol.

Comment: very true and I feel silly when you remind me but you tend to forget if you not using on regular bases :)